# Can I configure a twilio long number to opt a number back in

Tags: twilio

If a customer sends STOP to my app's twilio number, twilio will block me sending to that number until the customer texts START. Is there any way around this so that if the customer gave me consent verbally, for example, I can turn the number back on? Or can I configure a long code so that I handle the consent in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way around this other than having the customer [send an SMS saying START, YES or UNSTOP](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-STOP-BLOCK-and-CANCEL-SMS-STOP-filtering-) to your number.

Note, when a user opts out of getting messages from one of your Twilio numbers, so you could contact them on a different Twilio number if you had different reason to believe that the user wanted to opt in again without sending one of the above messages.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, philnash. Based on a support request I sent, it sounds like long numbers or the whole account can be configured by Twilio to not handle the opt in/opt out and leave that to your app. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Hey Bryan, yes, I believe that's correct and you need to get someone in support to sort that out for you.